# Create window based in text

Tags: c, winapi

I want to know, how I can creta a simple window, based on a "window" writed on a txt file, or better, how I can get the size of this "window", get in pixel, height and width, and get the title.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: basically nothing, because, I don't know the APi, or command, with I can get the size of character in pixel >x

Comment: For starters, in a text-based UI, there are no "pixels", the smallest unit is the "character". You can treat a single character cell as a single pixel, so for a function like `print_string_at_xy(const char *str, const int x, const int y)` then `x` and `y` is a character position.

Comment: No no, I want to create a FORM, using coordination writed on a text file... like on the picture

Comment: If you want windows etc. to be of fixed size, then you need the size to be relative to something else in the text file. In the example you posted, you need to have the outer screen as well, or at least set the relations somewhere. Otherwise don't use fixed widths/heights, but calculate them from the contents; For example if you have a window with a button, calculate the min size of the button, then you add padding around the button and you get the minimum window size.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate how much each "**|**" and "**-**" in pixels have, and multiplicate it with how many you find in each "part", then you just create the window with this infos, and to get the window caption you can simply search for alphabetic chars, because theres only the caption and the "|" and "-" besides it.

Comment: How I can calculate the size of "|" and "-" in pixels ?
Without GDI, using only the winapi ?

Comment: GDI is part of the Win32 API. The size is determined by the font in use, its size, the system DPI. It all depends on what you plan to use it for. There is already a text format for specifying Win32 Dialogs, take a look at dialog templates.